# starting and stopping hadoop daemons/processes in a cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a linux cluster with 9 nodes and I have installed hadoop 1.0.2. I have a GIS program that I am running using multiple slaves. I need to measure the speedUp of my program by using say 1, 2, 3, 4 .. 8 slave nodes. I use start-all.sh/stop-all.sh script to start/stop my cluster once I make changes in the conf/slaves file by varying the number of slaves.
But I am getting wierd errors while doing so, and it feels that I am not using the correct technique to add/remove slave nodes in the cluster.

Any help regarding the ideal "technique to make changes in slaves file and to restart the cluster" will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely is that you are not allowing Hadoop to gracefully remove the nodes from the system.

What you want to be doing is [*decommissioning*](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html#decommission) the nodes so that HDFS has times to re-replicate the files elsewhere. The process is essentially to add some nodes to an `excludes` file. Then, you run `bin/hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`, which reads the configurations and refreshes the cluster's view of the nodes.

When adding nodes and even perhaps when removing nodes, you should think about running the [rebalancer](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html#rebalancing). This will spread the data out evenly and would help in some performance you may see if new nodes don't have any data.